# button breaking app while selecting option

Tags: android, crash, lang

This script below is SettingsActivity.java

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    Context context;
    FragmentActivity activity;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    Button changelanguage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        this.context = this;

        //set toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // close on back button pressed
                finish();
            }
        });

        //set fragment to MyPreferenceFragment
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();

        loadLocale();
        activity = this;


        //set change language button
        changelanguage = findViewById(R.id.change_lang_btn2);
        changelanguage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Array of languages to dispaly in AlertDialog
                final String[] listitems ={"English","Spanish | Español","Portuguese | Português","French | français"};

                // Create AlertDialog to display list of languages
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle("Choose Language..");
                alert.setSingleChoiceItems(listitems, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        if (i == 0){
                            //set English
                            setLocale("en");
                            recreate();
                        }
                        else if (i == 1){
                            //set Spanish
                            setLocale("es");
                            recreate();
                        }
                        else if (i == 2){
                            //set Portuguese
                            setLocale("pt");
                            recreate();
                        }
                        else if (i == 3){
                            //set french
                            setLocale("fr");
                            recreate();
                        }

                        //dismiss alert dialog when language is selected
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        //save data to sharedpreferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("lang_settings",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("My_lang",lang);
        editor.apply();
    }

    //load language saved in shared preferences
    public void loadLocale(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("lang_settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = prefs.getString("My_lang", "");
        setLocale(language);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

This script below is Activity_Settings.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.riipo.gt.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/content"
            class="com.riipo.helpers.MyPreferenceFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/change_lang_btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/change_language_button"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[This is the error I'm getting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxd5r.jpg)

I will now describe the problem, the script is a way to change the language of my app through a button inside the configuration area, this way the script is inside SettingsActivity.java you click the button, it appears the options to be selected and when you select the application breaks.

showing the error message above, is to be a simple system of language exchange but there are some days that I am hitting on it, could someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you replacing a Fragment with the same Fragment? The Fragment is already in the XML. But I think you want to use           `name="com.riipo.helpers.MyPreferenceFragment"` instead of `class="com.riipo.helpers.MyPreferenceFragment"`.

Comment: i changed but the error persist

Comment: And remove this:         `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();`

Comment: Now works, thanks soo much!

Comment: Now works but change only on the button page, i can do something to change global?